# Is this a good approach for a BayeuxClient class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is this a good approach for a BayeuxClient class?

Reading cometd reference book, Chapter 6 Java Libraries, I created this BayeuxClient class.

As a newbie to cometd, I would like to know if this class has any flaws:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;

public class CometD_Client extends BayeuxClient
{
    private URL BayeuxServer_URL;

    private HttpClient JettyHttpClient;

    private Map<String, Object> TransportOptions;

    private ClientTransport C_Transport;

    private ClientSession C_Session;

    private boolean HandIsShaken£ = false;

    private final ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener MyChannelListener;

    public CometD_Client(URL BayeuxServer_URL)
    {
        this.BayeuxServer_URL = BayeuxServer_URL;

        // Create (and eventually set up) Jetty's HttpClient;
        JettyHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        JettyHttpClient.start();

        // Prepare the transport;
        TransportOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        ClientTransport C_Transport = 
            LongPollingTransport.create(TransportOptions, 
                                        JettyHttpClient  );

        C_Session = new BayeuxClient(URL, C_Transport);

        C_Session.handshake();

        HandIsShaken£ = 
            C_Session.waitFor(1000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);

        if(HandIsShaken£)
        {
            // TO DO: Output that the handshake had succeed;
        }
        else
        {
            // TO DO: Output that the handshake had failed;
        }

        MyChannelListener = new AChannelListener();

        C_Session.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener
        (
         new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel ThisMetaChanel,
                                  Message msg)
            {
                // TO DO: Output msg to check it out;

                C_Session.getChannel("/myBroadcast/myChannel").subscribe
                (
                 new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener()
                 {
                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel ThisMetaChanel,
                                          Message msg)
                    {
                        // TO DO: Handle the received messages to this chaned;
                    }
                 }
                );
            }
         }
        );
    }

    public boolean GetIfHandIsShaken£()
    {
        return HandIsShaken£;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I have no idea how to type the last character on my keyboard which makes modification harder:

   > ```
   > public boolean GetIfHandIsShaken£()
   > ```

   It's better to use only ASCII letters.
2. See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions* and [The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, 6.1 Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/):

   > Class and Interface Type Names
   >
   > Names of class types should be descriptive nouns or noun phrases, not overly long, in mixed
   >   case with the first letter of each word capitalized.
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > Names of fields that are not final should be in mixed 
   >   case with a lowercase first letter and the first letters of 
   >   subsequent words capitalized.

   `CometD_Client` could have a more descriptive classname too. Every CometD client could have been called `CometdClient`. Why is it special? Try to put that into the name.
3. > ```
   > TransportOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   > ```

   This could be in the same line as the declaration:

   ```
   private Map<String, Object> transportOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   ```
4. `HttpClient` has a `stop()` method. I suppose you should call it somewhere.